# Quand utiliser « en » ou « le » pour remplacer une proposition ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Extraits de *Advanced French Grammar* de V. Mazet :

- Page 142 :

  > If an object's antecedent is an entire clause, use le (l') as the object pronoun. Exemple :
  >
  > Je ne t'ai pas dit **que j'allais quitter mon poste** ? = *I didn't tell you that I was quitting my job?*
  >   → Je ne te **l**'ai pas dit?

  Pourquoi pas « je ne t'EN ai pas dit » ?
- Page 151 :

  > The pronoun **en** can replace a clause that's not introduced by **de**, but rather by **que.** [...] When a verb [...] that usually takes **de** + object, introduces a conjugated dependent verb, the proposition de (which only introduces an infinitive) won't appear in the sentene. Instead, the conjugated verb is introduced by **que**.
  >
  > Example: J'ai peur que nous soyons retard. → J'en ai peur.

  Pourquoi pas « je L'ai peur » ?

Au demeurant, quand employer « le » ou « en » dans le dessein de remplacer une proposition ? Je ne m'enquiers pas de leurs différences en général. Dans quelles conditions ces deux pronoms sont-ils interchangeables ?

Comment: Je n'ai pas l'impression qu'ils soient interchangeables...
Si on se réfère au premier exemple, on pourrait dire : "Je ne t'ai pas dit que j'allais le quitter" ("le" pour "le poste") ou "Je ne t'en ai pas parlé ?" ("en" pour "l'action" derrière le "que"), en changeant "dit" par "parlé".
On se retrouve ainsi sur la P151. "en" va remplacer un "que +...".

Comment: Merci de retranscrire les extraits cités le plus fidèlement possible.

Answer (score 6):

*Le* et *en* ne sont pas interchangeables.

*Le* est un pronom personnel COD qui peut remplacer une personne, une chose masculin ou une idée précédemment citée.

- Je prends **le train** → je **le** prends.
- Je vois **Pierre** → je **le** vois.
- « Je pense qu'il va pleuvoir » « Je le pense aussi. »

*En* est un pronom personnel COD qui peut remplacer une chose introduite par un article partitif (du, de la, des) :

- Bois-tu **du vin** ? — Non, je n'**en** bois jamais.

Il peut aussi être COI :

- Ils n'arrêtent pas de parler **de foot** ! Ils n'arrêtent pas d'**en** parler.

Par contre si le COI est une personne en bon français on emploiera comme pronom pour le remplacer « lui »,  « elle » ou « eux » de préférence à *en* :

- Elle parle toujours de son frère → elle parle toujours de lui.

*En* peut aussi remplacer un lieu :

- Quand vas-tu **aller à la boulangerie** ? — J'**en** viens !

On trouve *en* aussi dans certaines expressions :

- s’en aller
- en avoir assez
- s'en faire

Dans ces expressions il ne remplace rien.

Pour moi l'exemple que tu cites rentre dans le cas où *en* remplace une chose COI :

- J'ai peur que nous soyons retard. → J'ai peur de cela / de ce fait.

C'est « de ce fait/ cela » qui est repris par *en*, pas directement la proposition subordonnée de la question.

Comment: Merci. Pourriez-vous diriger votre réponse envers le remplacement d'une proposition ? Les différences en général sont inclus dans mon livre et y ont mis déjà en relief.

Comment: @LePressentiment: j'ai ajouté une phrase mais je ne vois pas en quoi le fait que la chose soit un nom commun ou une proposition puisse changer quelque chose.

Comment: Excusez-moi, je ne sens pas la différence... Par exemple, est-ce que je dois dire "Donc, c'etait un mensonge? Je le suspectais" ou "J'en suspectais"?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Une chose peut être une idée, bien sûr, j'ai rajouté un exemple « Je pense qu'il va pleuvoir » « Je le pense aussi. » c'est comme si on disait « je pense cela aussi ». Donc je **le** suspectais, **le** parce que c'est COD et pas COI.

Comment: Dans « J'en viens » le *en* est COI. Un complément circonstanciel de lieu deviendrait *y* ! « J'y chante » (dans le jardin).

Comment: Laure, est-ce qu'on peut dire "Je suspectais ça"?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Oui, bien sûr.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je viens de là → j'en viens, c'est un  lieu. On n'emploie pas « en » avec venir mais avec aller, j'y vais → je vais là. Si je dis « j'y viens » « y » n'est plus un lieu me semble-t-il.

Comment: Merci, Laure! :)

Comment: @Laure: c'est complètement contre-productif de dire que *en* peut remplacer un lieu alors que pour « venir » la seule raison qui fait qu'on utilise *en* c'est que la préposition (verbale, pas circonstancielle) qui vient avec venir c'est *de*. Et tu as déjà traité le cas de *de*. C'est *y* qui est utilisé pour tous les groupes introduits par *dans*, *sur*, *autour*, *à*, *devant*, … (i.e. tous les groupes circonstanciels de lieu). Ta réponse est trompeuse.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est une explication très classique qui me convient et que j'ai adopté [par exemple](http://www.french.hku.hk/starters/structures/06_pronoms2.htm) mais tu en trouves d'autres - ma grammaire Larousse du français contemporain par exemple dit que en peut-être complément circonstanciel. Je préfère dire qu'il est complément circonstanciel de lieu directement plutôt que dire qu'il est COI qui est mis pour un lieu [comme ici](http://www.connectigramme.com/yen.html/yen.htm).  Bon tout ça c'est des queues de cerises !.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'ai pas sous la main mes volumes de grammaire (en particulier mon *Bon usage*), mais mon instinct me donne à croire que peut-être "j'en ai peur" vient du fait que "avoir peur" est normalement suivi d'un complément amené par *de*. Il faudrait voir si d'autre verbes qui peuvent prendre un complément avec *de* ou une subordonnée *directe* (aucun ne me vient à l'esprit sur le moment) sont dans le même cas. Mazet, je l'ai déjà dit, a par moment une analyse qui laisse un peu à désirer.

J'essaierai de revenir sur la question dès que j'aurai mes références accessibles.

Comment: **Parler de** : « Elle parle toujours de ce qui lui est arrivé » -> Elle **en** parle toujours. Alors que si on a une personne on emploie de préférence le pronom personnel lui/elle/eux : « Elle parle toujours de de lui  » (de son frère).

Comment: Je pense que ça va plus loin que le fait que le verbe soit suivi de « de » ; c'est le fait que le verbe entraîne un **COI** qui détermine l'emploi de **en**. On dirait « je crains qu'il soit en retard » -> je **le** crains (« en » pas possible ici parce que craindre est suivi d'un COD - que ce COD soit un nom commun ou une action exprimée sous forme de proposition).

Comment: @Laure Pas d’accord. Dans le cas de ton COD, le verbe n’est pas suivi d’un *de*, sauf partitif, et dans ce cas on utilise bien *en*. Il me semble que c’est bien le *de* qui fait surgir le *en*. À part dans les expressions figées, le *en* remplace effectivement un *de* dans tous les exemples de ta réponse.

Comment: @Édouard: Non, un pronom personnel (ici en) ne peut pas remplacer une préposition (ta dernière phrase), il remplace un groupe de mots qui peut contenir ou non une préposition.

Comment: Je cite le Grevisse, 14ᵉ édition, 676 : « *En* joue le role d’un syntagme introduit par *de*. » et 679 « L’antécédent de *en* et de *y*. » d) « Ce peut être un verbe, une phrase, etc. »

Comment: @Laure parler ne remplis pas mes condition précisément parce que la subordonnée est précédée de "de"...

Comment: C'est le fait que le V introduise complément/subordonnée par "de" qui entraîne le remplacement du groupe complément par "en". Il me semble que les seules prépositions qui puissent introduire une subordonnée sont "de" et "à". Or si le verbe est suivi de "à" le groupe de mots qui suit est COI et donc ne rentre pas dans la question du PO qui porte sur **le** (qui ne peut-être que COD). C'est le pronom personnel "y" qui remplace propositions ou noms communs introduits par "à". *Je pense à changer de métier-> J'y pense*. Par contre: *je pense qu'il viendra -> Je le pense* (sub. COD)

Comment: Et la question sur laquelle nous nous penchons est justement "Pourquoi la subordonnée complément de *avoir peur*, bien qu'elle ne soit PAS introduite par *de* est-elle remplacée par *en*?" Un comparaison avec *parler*, où la subordonnée est justement introduite par une *de* qui résout la question de manière explicite, n'est absolument pas pertinente.